# Why do we need to register reflection service on gRPC server

Tags: reflection, grpc

I was going through this code of gRPC server. Can anyone tell me the need for reflection used [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/helloworld/greeter_server/main.go#L65)

**Code :**

```
func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    // Register reflection service on gRPC server.
    reflection.Register(s)
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Server reflection is not necessary to run the helloworld example.

The helloworld example is also used as a server reflection example, that's why you see the reflection registering code there.

More about server reflection:
Server reflection is a service defined to provides information about publicly-accessible gRPC services on a gRPC server. Tutorial available here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/server-reflection-tutorial.md

Comment: `reflection.Register(s)
 if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
 }`  Hence, I can safely remove this code, right?

Comment: Yes I write the sample myself and this line of code never comes to me.

Answer (score 17):

server-based-reflection is something that you will not need to build your day-to-day gRPC APIs.

This is a special instruction which exposes all the publicly accessible gRPC services on a gRPC server.
What this means essentially is that anyone can request your gRPC server to emit out details of the RPC service methods, request-response structures.

**Where is this used?**

This is used at places where you want to. dynamically call gRPC APIs. By dynamically I mean, the client does not need to hold the proto data-structures and register the RPC client stub.

- [grpCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) - curl gRPC services
- [gRPC transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding) - exposing json APIs on gRPC servers

Comment: So is registering reflection something that should be generally discouraged, due to any potential security reasons?